# Difference equation of second order system with zero

Tags: control-theory, recurrence-relations

> I saw from lecture notes that difference equation of a first order system is like this:
>
> **(1)**
> $$
> G(s)=\frac{K}{\tau s+1}
> $$
> **(2)**
> $$
> G(z)=\frac{K(1-A)}{z-a}, A=\exp (-T / \tau)
> $$
> **(3)**
> $$
> G(z)=\frac{K(1-A) z^{-1}}{1-A z^{-1}}=\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}
> $$
> **(4)**
> $$
> y(k)=A y(k-1)+K(1-A) x(k-1)
> $$

1. What happens between **(3)** and **(4)** ? It looks like inverse Z-transform but according to table
   $$
   \frac{z^{-1}}{1-a z^{-1}}
   $$
   should transform into this:
   $$
   a^{k}, k=1,2,3, \ldots
   $$
2. How can I find the difference equation of systems like this:
   $$
   T(s)=\frac{A s+B}{s^{2}+C s+D}
   $$

Comment: between the third and fourth steps the fact that $z^{-1}$ is a shift operator is used, i.e. $z^{-1}x(z)$ can be written in the time domain as $x(k-1)$. after that (3) is written in the form a difference equation.